# Best Robot for Simulation

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-humble, path-planning

Can you guys suggest me a Robot with 6 or 7 degree of Freedom which works well with Ros Humble for my Thesis. It will be only on a simulated environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do. I assume you want to do path planning.

If you just need a kinematic model, and you want to build your own path planning algorithm for that model, you can choose any URDF robot you can find. [Here](https://github.com/robot-descriptions/awesome-robot-descriptions) you have an exhaustive list of URDF robots.

If you need a complete simulated environment to run and compare existing path planning algorithms and view and run trajectories, I would follow [MoveIt's documentation](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html) for a setup with the Panda robot.

Comment: ok Thanks, is it possible to integrate the other Robots(other than Panda Robot) with Moveit, do you think it will work well in a Simulated Environment like Gazebo.

Comment: If you have the URDF, you can generate the Moveit config for any robot and use all the tools that Moveit offers.